# Axios interceptor is not getting the current user auth token from vuex store

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework, axios

I'm using Axios to send user input to DRF api and it returns an auth token. I'm saving the token in vuex store. In another component. I'm trying to request another api endpoint with Axios with the latest token in the request headers. The issue I'm having is that Axios will  either send the request with no token at all or with the token of the previous user that was logged in. It does not get the current token from the vuex store. I used Axios interceptors hoping that would help but it did not.

Login.vue

```
<script>

export default {
  name: 'Login',
  data () {
    return{
      email: null,
      password: null,

      token: '',

    }
    
  },
  props: {
    
  },

  methods: {
    submitForm () {

      this.$store.dispatch('loginUser',{
        email: this.email,
        password: this.password
      }).then(() =>{
        this.$router.push({ name: 'List' })

      }) .catch(err =>{
        console.log(err)
      })
      
    },

  }


}
</script>
```

store/index.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { createStore } from 'vuex'


export default createStore({
  state: {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
  },
  mutations: {
    getToken(state, token) {
      localStorage.setItem('token', token)
      state.token = token
      
      
    }
  },
  actions: {
    loginUser({ commit }, data){
      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/auth/login/',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: {
          'email': data.email,
          'password': data.password,
        }
      }).then(response =>{
        commit('getToken', response.data['key'])
      })
    }
  },
  modules: {
  }
})
```

List.vue

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
import store from '/src/store'
export default {
    name:'List',
    data () {
        return {
            entry: []
        }
    },

    created() {
        axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config){
            let token = store.state.token
            config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token;
            return config;
        })
        axios({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/journal/',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        
      }).then(response =>{

          this.entry = response.data


        
      }) .catch(err =>{
          console.log(err)
      })
    }
}
</script>
```

I thought the point of the interceptor was to get the token before actually making the get request, but it does not seem to be doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure why this works but rewriting my loginUser action like this solves my issue.

```
actions: {
    loginUser({ commit }, data){
      return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

      
      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8000/auth/login/',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        data: {
          'email': data.email,
          'password': data.password,
        }
      }).then(response =>{
        commit('getToken', response.data['key'])
        resolve()
      }).catch(err => {
        reject(err)
      })
    })
    }
  },
```

I think it's because return new Promise basically interrupts the the initial promise in Login.vue making sure the client doesn't make an api request without the correct token from the server but I'm not sure.